# LDAP - Use of wildcard on MemberOf filter

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, wildcard, directorysearcher

I need to get all users and their groups from a specific category.

Examples of users :

```
user  | memberof
user1 | CN=group_1,OU=Groupes,OU=CR 1,DC=zcam,DC=ztech
user1 | CN=group_2,OU=Groupes,OU=CR 1,DC=zcam,DC=ztech
user2 | CN=group_2,OU=Groupes,OU=CR 1,DC=zcam,DC=ztech
user3 | CN=group_3,OU=Groupes,OU=CR 2,DC=zcam,DC=ztech
```

I need to get every user where `memberof` contains `OU=Groupes,OU=CR 1,DC=zcam,DC=ztech` (user1 and user2 from my example)

Following this doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/ADSI/search-filter-syntax) I tried the following syntaxes :

```
DirectoryEntry ldap = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ldap))
{
    // Works but return everything
    searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=*))";

    // Works but only for one group
    searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=group_1,OU=Groupes,OU=CR 1,DC=zcam,DC=ztechh))";

    // Doesn't work because searcher.FindAll().Count returns 0
    searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=*,OU=Groupes,OU=CR 1,DC=zcam,DC=ztechh))";

    // searcher.FindAll().Count returns 0
    foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll()) 
    {
        [...]
    }
```

Following this (https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=00d29fa1db101fc01dcaf3231f96197f) I tried to change the wildcard `*` by a `%` but it didn't changed the result.

Comment: "All users and their groups" - so you want ths search to return both user *and* group objects?

Comment: Use the `System.DirctoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace instead, it's much easier - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found another way to do.
In fact, this property `OU=CR 1` in the `memberof` correspond to the division in my AD.
So I just filter like this :

```
DirectoryEntry ldap = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ldap))
{
    searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(division=CR 1))";

    foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll()) 
    {
        [...]
    }
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to get every user where memberof contains OU=Groupes,OU=CR 1,DC=zcam,DC=ztech (user1 and user2 from my example)

If I understand correctly, I think that sentence sums up what you're trying to do. You want to find all users who are a member of any group in that OU.

Active Directory doesn't let you use wildcards on any attribute that takes a `distinguishedName`. That includes `member` and `memberOf`. So the only way to do this is in two steps:

1. Find the `distinguishedName` of all groups in that OU.
2. Search for all users whose `memberOf` includes one of the values found in step 1.

Something like this (I haven't tested this against AD, so you might need to tweak it):

```
var groupSearch = new DirectorySearcher(
    new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Groupes,OU=CR 1,DC=zcam,DC=ztech"), //notice the OU
    "(objectClass=group)");

//if you don't do this, it will return *every* attribute, which is slower
groupSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

//build a user query with all the groups
var userFilter = new StringBuilder("(&(objectClass=user)(|");
using (var results = groupSearch.FindAll()) {
    foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
        userFilter.Append($"(memberOf={result.Properties["distinguishedName"][0]})");
    }
}
userFilter.Append(")");

var userSearch = new DirectorySearcher(
    new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=zcam,DC=ztech"),
    userFilter.ToString());

//userSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add(""); //add only the attributes you need to make it quicker

using (var results = userSearch.FindAll()) {
    foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Note that this will only find *direct* members of those groups. It won't return users that are in nested groups (when a user is in a group that is a member of one of these groups). If you want that, you can adjust the filter to include a special flag that tells AD to search recursively:

```
userFilter.Append($"(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={result.Properties["distinguishedName"][0]})");
```

Depending on your domain, you might want to be aware of two things:

1. This will not return users who have one of these groups as their primary group, since that relationship is not stored using `member`/`memberOf`.
2. If these groups have members from external trusted domains, then you'll end up finding Foreign Security Principal objects, instead of their actual user objects. That's a whole other thing to deal with, if it's an issue for you.

I've written a few articles on the subject, if you're curious. Start with this one: [Active Directory: What makes a member a member?](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html)

Answer (score 1):

edited version; extend for all your `group_X`

```
(
&(objectClass=user)
(|(memberof=CN=group_1,OU=Groupes,OU=CR 1,DC=zcam,DC=ztechh)
(memberof=CN=group_2,OU=Groupes,OU=CR 1,DC=zcam,DC=ztechh))
)
```